# Gstreamer - WARNING No decoder available for type 'application/x-id3'

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

**The command:** `$ gst-play-1.0 /home/username/test/baby.mp3`

**The result:**

```
Press 'k' to see a list of keyboard shortcuts.
Now playing /home/whiteknight/NXP_test/baby.mp3
WARNING No decoder available for type 'application/x-id3'.
WARNING debug information: gsturidecodebin.c(931): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0
ERROR Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in. for file:///home/whiteknight/NXP_test/baby.mp3
ERROR debug information: gsturidecodebin.c(998): no_more_pads_full (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
gstdecodebin2.c(4600): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPlayBin:playbin/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found:
Missing decoder: ID3 tag (application/x-id3)

Reached end of play list.
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-id3demux.html

So it has to be a part of gst-plugins-good.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/filelist

```
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstgoom2k1.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgsticydemux.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstid3demux.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstimagefreeze.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstinterleave.so

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with gmusicbrowser running in a Crouton installed Ubuntu/Xenial on a chromebook.

I solved it by installing gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad, gstreamer1.0-plugins-good and gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio from apt.

i also installed the ubuntu-restricted-extras apt package for the flac decoders.

gmusicbrowser could then play mp3 and flac.